# Is Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER has value of (2^53 - 1) in 32-bit computer

Tags: javascript, computer-science, bit, 32bit-64bit

The [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) refers that the `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` constant represents the maximum safe integer in JavaScript which has value of `2^53 - 1`.

**my question:** is `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` has also value of `(2^53 - 1)` in *32-bit* computer?

and if yes it has the same value how can JavaScript store this number `(2^53 - 1)` in *32 bits*?!

Comment: Yes. In multiple bytes, with multiple instructions

Comment: Numbers, according to the language spec, are 64-bit double-precision floating point values. A conforming JavaScript implementation on a 32-bit CPU must deal with that somehow. How? That's up to the implementors.

Comment: Also, why do you care? Are you encountering some specific problem?

Comment: Computers have supported double precision floating point for decades, long before there were 64-bit processors. They just store them in two 32-bit words.

Comment: This will help you https://superuser.com/questions/698312/if-32-bit-machines-can-only-handle-numbers-up-to-232-why-can-i-write-100000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. All JavaScript `Number`s are represented using IEEE 754 binary64 (A.K.A. double precision floating point). *This format takes 64 bits of space*, but most modern 32-bit processors support it natively, and even if they didn't, it would be possible to implement floating point operations in software.

The "32-bit" in 32-bit processor refers to the *[word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)) size*.